# speed up timer game in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer

hi i am building my first basic game in Xcode for the iPhone i have one issue its facing me 
 the game is snake eating food i need the correct way to speed up UIimageView .

i had try to speed up the NSTimer but ever time the level 1 work fine then when i go to level 2 the snake and the score not working correct ??

so please i need the correct way to increasing the speed of image without effecting the next level 
or the correct way to speed up the timer ..

if any one can help me i am ready to sure the code with him by e-mail need some help pleeeeeeease .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be easier (and faster) for the SO community to help if you provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to synthetically speed up the iOS simulator.
Your only option is to increase the firerate of your NSTimer.

Comment: ok thanks i need the correct way to move image on the screen then increasing the speed over time ??

Comment: If you are simply using UIImageViews - you can just set the views centre as you wish.